# How to set set JSON encoder in marshmallow?

Tags: python, json

How do I override the JSON encoder used the [marshmallow](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow) library so that it can serialize a `Decimal` field?I think I can do this by overriding `json_module` in the base `Schema` or `Meta` class, but I don't know how:

https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/blob/dev/marshmallow/schema.py#L194

I trawled all the docs and read the code, but I'm not a Python native.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to serialize a `Decimal` field (and keep the value as a number), you can override the default json module used by Marshmallow in its `dumps()` call to use `simplejson` instead.

To do this, just add a `class Meta` definition to your schema, and specify a `json_module` property for this class.

Example:

```
import simplejson

class MySchema(Schema):
    amount = fields.Decimal()

    class Meta:
        json_module = simplejson
```

Then, to serialize:

```
my_schema = MySchema()
my_schema.dumps(my_object)
```

Comment: Thank you!  I had been going crazy with this.  Works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is to use [`marshmallow.fields.Decimal`](http://marshmallow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api_reference.html#marshmallow.fields.Decimal) with `as_string=True`:

> This field serializes to a `decimal.Decimal` object by default. If you
>   need to render your data as JSON, keep in mind that the `json` module
>   from the standard library does not encode `decimal.Decimal`. Therefore,
>   you must use a JSON library that can handle decimals, such as
>   `simplejson`, or serialize to a string by passing `as_string=True`.

Comment: Note that if you use the `as_string=True` option, it will convert your numeric value to a string, which is probably not the behavior you want.

Comment: @ChrisHickman that's exactly the behaviour I'd want for a decimal field

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I endup changing the field on Schema to string. In my case, since I'm only going to return it in json, it really doesn't matter if it is string or decimal.

```
from marshmallow_sqlalchemy import ModelSchema
from marshmallow import fields
class CurrencyValueSchema(ModelSchema):
   class Meta:
       model = CurrencyValue
   value = fields.String()
```

My returned json:

```
{
   "currency_values": [
    {
      "id": 9, 
      "timestamp": "2016-11-18T23:59:59+00:00", 
      "value": "0.944304"
   }, 
   {
      "id": 10, 
      "timestamp": "2016-11-18T23:59:59+00:00", 
      "value": "3.392204"
   }, 
}
```